# Cannot write in separate lines in a TXT files in C

Tags: c, file, text, lines

ok so i have a structure of customers and i am trying to write each attribute of the customer in a separate line in a text file. Here is the code

```
custFile = fopen ("customers.txt", "w+");
fprintf(custFile, "%s", cust[cust_index].name);
fprintf(custFile, "\n");
fprintf(custFile, "%s", cust[cust_index].sname);
fprintf(custFile, "%s", cust[cust_index].id);
fclose(custFile);
```

The data is form the text file is outputted in one line

The data is fine, it is just printed in one line. When i gave my friend my code, it worked as it should.

P.s i dont know if it makes any difference but i am programming on a mac

Comment: Don't flush stdin, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Explanation about this behavior can be inferred from an answer already given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402673/adding-multiple-lines-to-a-text-file-output

Comment: Isn't `\r` the newline character on the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only adds one newline for the 3 fields.  Its possible this accounts for the problems you've encountered?  If not, note that some old apps on old macs may expect `\r` line separators.

You could address both issues if you factored out a function and used it to write all records and to test out different line separators

```
static void writeCustomer(FILE* fp, const Customer* customer,
                          const char* line_separator)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%s%s", customer->name, line_separator,
                                customer->sname, line_separator,
                                customer->id, line_separator);
}
```

which would be invoked like

```
writeCustomer(custFile, &cust[cust_index], "\n"); /* unix line endings */
writeCustomer(custFile, &cust[cust_index], "\r\n"); /* Windows line endings */
writeCustomer(custFile, &cust[cust_index], "\r"); /* Mac line endings */
```

Be aware that some apps won't display newlines for some of these line endings.  If you care about display in particular editors, check their capabilities with different line endings.

Comment: `\r` is not a newline on mac. `\n` is. the only diff between windows and all other relevant systems is that windows sometimes writes a `\r\n`. but mac using `\r` as the line separator is .. wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @user1961411: and no, your fault is that you do not use _ANY_ linebreaks in your `fprintf` calls. "%s" means just "print a string" and not "print a string AND include the linebreak".

Comment: @akira Both the wikipedia link you posted and [this previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) say that recent Macs use \n for newlines but older ones used \r.  Is my updated answer any better or do you still think its wrong?

Comment: @simonc: do you know how old your mac has to be to use `\r` as line-ending? do you consider 10years+ as important as to put that part of your answer to the top? it's a sidenote at best, just use `\n` and done. wordpad on windows will open such files very well, any other sane text-editor on the planet loves `\n`.